# Deserialize nested json with different property names

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a custom contract resolver to resolve property names in my model to those returned by a RESTful API call. This is an example API call:

```
{
    "record_id": "f461dc88-2a3c-428c-ad92-1d03477667cf",
    "company": "Palm Beach Photographics",
    "company_info": {
        "images": [
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=719",
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=653",
            "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=965"
        ],
        "industries": [
            "Real Estate",
            "Photo/Film",
            "Utilities/Energy/Infrastructure",
            "Emergency Services"
        ],
        "location_state": "FL",
        "overview": "Per fusce luctus diam hac dictum posuere non interdum conubia eleifend, fusce suscipit purus aliquam porttitor amet fames nostra sapien potenti fusce, quisque felis quisque ante fringilla nulla rutrum porta at inceptos mi per mattis rhoncus id."
    }
}
```

and my Models are as follows:

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CompanyInfo Info { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyInfo
{
    public IEnumerable<Uri> Images { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Industries { get; set; }

    public string Overview { get; set; }
}

public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{

    private Dictionary<string, string> PropertyMappings { get; }

    public CustomContractResolver(Dictionary<string, string> propertyMappings)
    {
        PropertyMappings = propertyMappings;
    }

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        var resolved = PropertyMappings.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var resolvedName);
        return (resolved) ? resolvedName : base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Without polluting my model with JsonProperty and other tags, how can I get the nested `company_info` to bind correctly? When I am deserializing the object using JsonConvert, I pass in property mappings as such:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _propertyMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Id", "record_id"},
        {"Name", "company"},
        {"Info.Images", "company_info.images"},
        {"Info.Industries", "company_info.industries"},
        {"Info.State", "company_info.location_state"},
        {"Info.Overview", "company_info.overview"}
    };
```

The Id and Name correctly bind, but none of the Info maps.

Comment: The mapper uses Reflection to get the property names. Your notation does not map to any existing property currently. Have your member object's properties resolve to the member object directly.

Comment: Sorry, are you suggesting I move the properties of Company Info into Company? Could you please provide an example of what you mean or elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change any property name to match with Json property and don't wanna use JsonProperty you can just fix your wrong property mapping to this

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _propertyMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Id", "record_id"},
        {"Name", "company"},
        {"Info", "company_info"},
        {"State", "location_state"}
    };
```

Just tell Deserializer to map name-to-name no need to put any nested object on it
hope it can solve your problem

Comment: Ah, perfect. That worked. I'm curious on how the resolution works though. When the contract resolver hits the Company Info I imagine it starts mapping Info to all properties under company Info. How does State get mapped to location_state afterwards?

Comment: i think in nested class they do the same as root class when it try to resolve `location_state` it check in custom mapping that the `location_state` are exist in mapping or not if not they map with the same name but if it exist it map with specific name we assigned

Comment: Please note, this approach opens a door to all sorts of ambiguities that can make debugging troublesome when there is any change in the underlying objects.

Comment: every way make the same debugging troublesome if you make an custom map for deserialize and you change your class without change your mapping

Comment: so how can we prevent from this ambiguity? How an we take care class names while serialization?

Comment: use JsonPropertyName or JsonProperty attribute base on your serializer, assuming that class name is property name refer in class https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 1):

The example you asked for, formatted here:

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CompanyInfo Info { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Uri> Info_Images { 
      get {
         return Info.Images;
      }
      set {
         if (Info == null) {
            Info = new CompanyInfo();
         }
         Info.Images = value 
      }
    }
    // etc., with the other properties.
}

public class CompanyInfo
{
    public IEnumerable<Uri> Images { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Industries { get; set; }

    public string Overview { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping could go as:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _propertyMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Id", "record_id"},
        {"Name", "company"},
        {"Info_Images", "company_info.images"},
        {"Info_Industries", "company_info.industries"},
        {"Info_State", "company_info.location_state"},
        {"Info_Overview", "company_info.overview"}
    };
```

Comment: {"Info_Industries", "company_info.industries"} wont wokr. the answer is wrong.